# Making my combo boxes independent in PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, combobox

I'm having some trouble with populating combo boxes with database content depending on what the user chooses in another combobox.
It works fine when I use one 'pair' of boxes. **COUNTRY -> PLAYER**. But when I add several **COUNTRY->PLAYER** on the same page, all my players get chosen by the first **COUNTRY BOX**.
Here is a snap of my code, it is created from [this webpage example](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".country").change(function(){
            var id=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax-search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $(".player").html(html);
                    console.log(id);
                } 
            });        
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $counter++;
         echo '<select class = "country" name="singleBetTeam[' . $counter . ']">';
         echo "<option selected = 'selected'> COUNRTY</option>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
               $data = $row['team_name'];
               echo '<option value="'.$data.'">'.$data.'</option>';
             }
             echo '</select><select name="singleBetStar[' . $counter . ']" class="player">';
          echo '<option selected="selected"> PLAYER </option></select>';
     }
```

The problem is that when I choose Germany in the first Combobox, then I get the German players all of the other combo boxes for player. This is depending on the fact that I check for class="player" in the javascript but I don't know how to create this connection?

[image]

Comment: `$(".player").html(html)` updates _all_ the elements with that class. You need to select the one that's adjacent to the country box that they changed, by using DOM traversal methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only update the combobox following the one that the user changed, rather than all elements matching the `player` class. You can use the `context:` option to `$.ajax` to pass the changed element to the callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".country").change(function() {
        var id=$(this).val();

        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax-search.php",
            data: {id: id},
            cache: false,
            context: this;
            success: function(html) {
                $(this).next(".player").html(html);
                console.log(id);
            } 
        });

    });
});
```